# Move object across grid in direction of heading

Tags: c#, graphics, geometry

In c# winforms, I am drawing a figure onto the form. and you can move the figure around in a 2d game-like fashion. Left and right will turn the figure in a direction (Changes it's heading), and the up and down keys will move the figure forwards or backwards (change it's velocity). However, lets say the figure is pointed at 135 degrees. How would I know to move the x,y coordinates accordingly.

in the image below the figure is at coordinates (140, 140) with a heading of 135. To move forward, how would I calculate the new position.

[image]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kupe2ZKK58) is the big picture of what I am trying to create

Comment: may you provide your code for clarification of what you want

Comment: None, exists. I want to know how to move in the direction of a bearing. Meaning i have starting position X and Y, and a Bearing of q. How do I update X and Y to move in the direction of q

Comment: @Oxymoron do you want to move object in this direction or do you want to turn it's direction ?

Comment: Try: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=moving+on+a+vector for a start. This really is a mathematics question. Once you've got a formula, come back if you are having trouble implementing it.

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha Move object in direction. I am already able to turn it's direction.

Comment: @MattBurland I'm currently researching and will post the answer should I find it before someone else can.

Comment: @Oxymoron you should change y corresponding to x using mathamatic formula y=mx+c

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha define M and C

Comment: m is gradient  and  c is intercept .you can increase x position using x++ but y is corresponding to x according to formula y=mx+c .so you need a c# function to find y when you know x .take a look at http://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html 
simply what y=mx+c is do it calculate y according to given x 
m is equal to tan(135) in your case.but you have to care about x,y cordinate because in c# y increase from top to bottom

Comment: How do I solve for c?

Comment: @Oxymoron take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y=mx+c will help you to decide y position according to x's coordinate .
take a look at this image [image]

x1,y1 is 140,140 in your case.

```
y=mx+c
c=0 because 140,140 
y=x tan(45°)
y=x  hence tan(45°)=1
y=x
```

so in c#

```
void move object1(){
  int speed=2;
  x+=speed;
  y+=speed;

}//but this is really easy because 135 degree and start point is 140,140 but when those are not equal this will bit different
```